# some excel automation that mimics dragging corner anchor

Tags: excel

You know how in excel you can have a value like `row_01`, and if you do the drag fill it will auto increment the row number. Is there a way to do that through code or something? Because what if I wanted 10,000 rows? I don't want to sit and drag for that long.

Comment: Try recording a macro while autofilling a few rows and see what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure first cell contains a 1 then...

Simply Record a macro...
it will show you how to do it.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:A10000"), Type:=xlFillSeries
    Range("A1:A1000").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for a macro. First Go To: the last cell to be populated and insert something there (`z` would serve). Then go back to the cell to be "dragged", select it, go to the cell immediately below it, Ctrl+Shift+Down and Enter.